# How to host .pem under /.well-known in microsoft azure? ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service, ssl-certificate

Goal: I'm trying host a public certificate (`.pem`) under https://example.com/.well-known/XXX.pem in Azure. I'm using an ASP.NET Core MVC project.

I have added the certificate in the project folder `wwwroot/.well-known/xxxx.pem`.

I am able to verify the file exists in the build output (`Bin/Release` folder). This correlates well with the project build settings:

```
Build Action: Content
Copy To output directory: Copy Always
```

However, once the deployment takes place, it cannot be accessed via the actual web, hosted by azure web app. It returns a 404 file not found.

I have verified by jumping into kudu console, that the file does in fact exists in the `wwwroot/.well-known` folder. I suspect Azure is blocking the content from being served up.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd host something like this in **Azure Keyvault** - not in the file system ....

Comment: Ensure your `.pem file path` is precise,  you should verify static file middleware, and customize if needed. Check URL rewriting, IIS configuration (Windows App Service), and server logs. Use local testing, Kudu console, and network tools for troubleshooting. Considering your scenario,  you could think of  `Azure Key Vault` and stay updated on Azure documentation.  Your configuration should be `FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "wwwroot", ".well-known")),
    RequestPath = "/.well-known"`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code to host a .pem certificate in the .well-known folder of an Azure App service.

I added the code below to my Program.cs class, as shown below :

```cs
app.MapControllerRoute(
               name: "well-known",
               pattern: ".well-known/{*fileName}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Certificate", action = "GetCertificate" });
```

**Program.cs** :

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
               name: "well-known",
               pattern: ".well-known/{*fileName}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Certificate", action = "GetCertificate" });

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.Run();
```

**CertificateController.cs**:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
namespace certapp.Controllers
{
    public class CertificateController : Controller
    {
        [Route(".well-known/{fileName}")]
        public IActionResult GetCertificate(string fileName)
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", ".well-known", fileName);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
                return Content(fileContent, "text/plain");
            }
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
}
```

I added Certificate.pem to the .well-known folder, the wwwroot folder, and the root directory, as shown below:

**.well-known folder**  :

[image]

**Local OutPut** :

[image]

I successfully published the app to Azure App Service, as shown below:

[image]

**Azure Web App Output**:
[image]